className styling cannot work in react native
enter image description here
I have faced a problem where when I change the style in className for tailwind-css, it does not change anything in my virtual device, before this I have follow the intrusction from the nativewind v2 wbesite where everything is working fine until there's no changes when I change the style, anyon react-native or tailwind-css pros know what is the problem ?
My tailwind.config.js
tailwind.config.js

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./app.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

package.json
{
  "name": "app_stack",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "reset-project": "node ./scripts/reset-project.js",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "expo lint"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "expo": "~51.0.28",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.9",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.23",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~51.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

My babel.config.js
babel.config.js

module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ["nativewind/babel"],
  };
};

My app.json
app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "app_stack",
    "slug": "app_stack",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro",
      "output": "static"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router"
    ],
    "experiments": {
      "typedRoutes": true
    }
  }
}


you need to create global.d.ts file in your project's root and put this nativewind decorator.
/// <reference types="nativewind/types" />

I struggled with the same issue. And this is what worked for me.
First checked the NativeWind installation by calling verifyInstallation in your root component, like below :
 // Ensure to call inside a component, not globally

    verifyInstallation();

On the Android emulator, this gave me the error: "NativeWind received no data. Please refer to http://nativewind.dev/troubleshooting#nodata".
This error occurs when NativeWind has not injected the StyleSheet information into your application.
The possible causes suggested there were:

Ensure that you are importing your .css file. You should be importing the .css in the global scope of your application (before React renders).
withNativeWind is missing or is overwritten (in metro.config.js)

In my expo-router based app, I imported 'global.css' in my root level 'index.tsx'. And the className now works.
import React from 'react';
...
import '../global.css';
...

const App = () => {
// Your code
...

}

The same issue is discussed in the following thread as well.
https://github.com/nativewind/nativewind/issues/1050#issuecomment-2378814536.
